# Mysql get sum of column_1 based on distinct value in column_2

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table:

```
+-----+--------+ 
|col1 |   col2 |
+-----+--------+
|   1 |     12 | 
|   1 |     12 |
|   2 |     13 |
|   4 |     15 | 
|   2 |     13 |
|   3 |     14 |
|   3 |     14 |
|   1 |     12 |
+-----+--------+
```

I'm looking for Total sum of col2 for distinct col1.

Comment: Use `SUM()` and `GROUP BY`.

Comment: I have tried a couple of things. I couldn't get the kind of result. Maybe a query would help.

Comment: Better way of thinking about the solution - you're looking to get a _sum_ of all values within `col2` for each _grouping_ of `col1`

Comment: @AnthonyForloney I need total sum not group sum. It's two steps. First i get the distinct value of col2 then i add col1.

Comment: what would be the expected output for your sample shown in your question?

Comment: What is your PRIMARY KEY? How do you uniquely identify rows in your table? And what is the desired result?

Comment: Please share the expected output from this above sample.

Answer (score 0):

```
select col1, sum(col2) from mytable group by col1
```

Comment: I edited my question. I need total sum once i get the distinct value.

Comment: @Yen - please could you add some description as to how your query works to satisfy the original question (the sum of distinct values for column 1). Simply providing the solution does not help the OP to understand how to solve the problem in other situations.

Answer (score 0):

With:

```
SELECT DISTINCT col1, col2 FROM tablename
```

get the distinct rows of the table and then get the sum:

```
SELECT SUM(col2) AS total
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT col1, col2 FROM tablename) t
```

Answer (score 0):

then you just have to add another query
select sum(col2) from myTable